# Android location extras not set

Tags: android, kotlin, location

Strange issue with location bundles:
At some point, location.extras not accepting assignments

```
val l=Location("SRC")
val x = Bundle()
l.extras = x
```

and then

```
l.extras == x
```

returns **false!**

How come?!

Consequently,

```
Bundle().also{location.extras=it}.putBoolean("Foo", false)
```

creates location.extras with an empty bundle.

Why? Any reasonable explanation?

Comment: *How come?!*  It is obvious ... take a look at source of setExtras in Location class ... then check if Bundle have overrided equals ...

Comment: Yeah, silly indeed. Though they ought to document it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Selvin mentioned, in [The sources of Location.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/Location.java)

```
public void setExtras(Bundle extras) {
    mExtras = (extras == null) ? null : new Bundle(extras);
}
```

That makes it equivalent to

```
val l = Location("SRC")
val x = Bundle(x)
l.extras = x // means l.extras = Bundle(x) = Bundle(Bundle(x))
```

and

```
Bundle(x) != x
```

Ought to

```
Bundle().let{location.extras=it; location.extras}.setBoolean(...)
```

That would retrieve back the right instance to be edited. *Be careful with one-liner challenges.*